# Detecting newlines in a Python string

Tags: python, sockets

I'm having a little trouble with detecting new lines in a Python string.

I have a client and a server program.  They communicate through a socket.  I've included what I believe to be the only relevant code.

Client:

```
 socket.send("message goes here\r\n.\r\n")
```

Server:

```
 message = socket.recv(500)
 "\r\n." in message # evaluates to True
 "\r\n.\r\n" in message # evaluates to False
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting the last statement to evaluate to true.  The second statement is not an acceptable test for my case.

Comment: what does `repr(message)` show?

Comment: Assuming you're using TCP, you need to remember that it is a *stream* - a stream of bytes. There is no guarantee that everything you `send` in one "message" will be received on the other side in one call to `recv`.  You'll need to "packetize" the information yourself by adding some sort of application-layer protocol on top of TCP.

Comment: @MattDMo, repr(message) prints out what I'd expect, with the new lines.

JonathonReinhart Do you mind explaining that a little further?

Comment: `>>> "\r\n.\r\n" in "message goes here\r\n.\r\n"` returns `True` here.